# Navigation Bar extends beyond Body in Chrome

Tags: html, css

When viewing my site in responsive mode on Chrome, my navigation bar extends beyond the `body` when the screen size is below 1300px. See image below:

[image: .nav-container extends beyond body.]

I've highlighted the offending element in dev tools and it appears to be my `nav-container` div. Below 1300px, it appears to have a negative right side position value:

[image: position property has a negative right side value.]

```js
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position:relative;
    min-height:100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width:100%;
}

.nav-container{
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:99;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transition:0.5s;
}

.logo-container{
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.logo-banner{
    height:75px;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

nav{
    position:fixed;
    text-align:left;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background:rgb(16, 10, 48);
    transform:translateX(-100%);
    transform-origin:top;
    transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
    z-index:10;
}

nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

nav li {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

//This code for desktop
@media screen and (min-width:1000px){    
    .nav-toggle-button{
        display:none;
    }

    .nav-container{
        position: fixed;
        width:100%;
        z-index:99;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    nav{ 
        display:flex;
        justify-self: flex-end;
        align-items:center;
        margin-right:1em;
        transform:translateX(0%);
        position:static;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }

    nav li{
        position:relative;
    }

    nav ul {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .logo-container{
        margin-left:1em;
        justify-self: flex-start;
        width:200px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="nav-container">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <a href="./"><img class="logo-banner" src="images/logo-banner.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>

            <button class="nav-toggle-button">
                <span class="hamburger"></span>
            </button>

            <nav>
                <ul class="anim">
                    <li><a href="./" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="buying.html" class="nav-link">Land Acquisition</a></li>
                    <li><a href="selling.html" class="nav-link">Land Disposal</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="projects.html" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>     
            </nav>
        </div>
     <!-- The rest of my HTML here -->
</body>
```

I've already tried adding `overflow-x:hidden;` and setting a `width:100%;` to the body but no luck. Oddly, this issue doesn't exist in Firefox for some reason.

Any insight appreciated, thanks.

Comment: but you applied `overflow-x` to the mobile css!! and why don't you added media query to the mobile css

Comment: @KALITA why is that a bad thing? Can ```overflow-x``` not be used for mobile CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've given your `nav` `position: fixed`. It is taken out of the normal document flow. `Placing overflow: hidden` on a parent won't help as it will cut it.
I recommend assigning a `max-width` of `100vw` to the `nav` element to prevent it from extending beyond the viewport.

```
.nav {
    max-width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: This has helped in that it has stopped the content overflowing, but there's still this empy space to the right of the page. It's not horizontal scrolling, as everything still fits in the viewport, it just has this white space inside it. 

Any idea why this is doesn't happen in Firefox?

Comment: I see. If everything is still within viewport, then consider that the white space you see is because that your content does not fill up the entire width of the viewport, for that, I recommend the same CSS property that I've mentioned on my answer on relevant elements . If the white space persists, examine margins or paddings. Currently viewers can't run your layout properly - consider creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you seek further insight

Answer (score 0):

I have the best solution for you just add

```
*{padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

at the top of your style.css file and save it now you'll see your nav is in a fixed position.